# List and Remove directories in an archive

Tags: bash, archive

I wonder how to list the content in an archive file and remove some directories from it?

For example, I have an archive file `data.tar`.

1. I would like to list its content without extracting it. Is it possible to control the level of directory for viewing? I mean not necessarily every files, but just down to some level of the path.
2. I also would like to remove some directories  matching `"*/count1000"` from it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

to see the contents of the tar file,

```
tar tvf mytar.tar
```

to extract a file,

```
tar xvf mytar.tar myfile.txt
```

to delete a file

```
tar -f mytar.tar --delete */count1000
```

Comment: How to remove some directories matching "*/count1000" from it.

Comment: Is it possible to control the level of directory for viewing? I mean not necessarily every files, but just down to some level of the path. Thyanks

Answer (score 1):

You can strip the 1st path component with:

```
cat myarchive.tar.gz | tar -tzf - | grep --only-matching -e "/.*"
```

You can strip the 2nd path component with:

```
cat myarchive.tar.gz | tar -tzf - | grep --only-matching -e "/.*/.*"
```

etc.